# Solve arithmetic question using calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Thomaskutty is starting a new business. he knows that most business when they start run at loss. Thomaskutty  predict that in the first month he will lose \$2200, in the second he will loose \$1800 and in the third he will lose $1400 and this pattern will continue with each passing month (like arithmetic sequence where a=-2200 and d=400). Given the cumulative (running) total profit after n months is given by S(n)=n/2 (2a+(n-1)d) use calculus to determine:

a) The last month Emma will incur a net loss

b) The amount of loss during that month (given tn=a+(n-1)d)

c) The maximum cumulative loss (minimum cumulative profit) that Emma will experience

My working for this is quite stupid in my opinion. I try to work out these question by using the arithmetic sequence formula when we are asked to use calculus. I am not sure where to start to use calculus to solve this
Here is my working out:

a) $tn+(n-1)d$
= -2200 + (7-1)*400 = 200

Thus during the seventh month it will be the start of the positive.

-2200 + (6-1)*400 = -200
In the sixth month it will be the last month of a loss.

b) the loss on the last month will be \$-200.

c)The maximum cumulative loss by Emma will be

n/2 (2a+(n-1)d)
6/2 (2(-2200)+(6-1)*400 = \$-7200 loss

Is my working out for the answer correct and if they are how can I use calculus to solve the questions?

Answer (score 1):

Since we are using a calculus method, let's use the function $p(t)=-2400+400t$.

I start with $-2400$ because averaged over a month, adds up to only $-2200$ negative.

a. $p(t)=0$, which means $t=6$. So her last month of net loss is the sixth month (she stops losing money at $t \geq 6$, which is the start of the seventh month.

b. $\displaystyle \int_5^6p(t)\,dt=-200$, or a $\$200$ loss. You can reaffirm this with the arithmetic sequence

c. The maximum cumulative loss is at the point where she stops losing money further, or at $t=6$. This amount is $\displaystyle \int_0^6 p(t)\,dt=-7200$, or a $\$7200$ loss.

Comment: Your answers are all correct, and this is a way to use calculus. The only part that I think is important is to use -2400+400t, that way it averages out to -2200,-1800,-1400 during each month,.

Comment: can you show me how you got -2400? Like how do we average over a month to get -2400

Comment: at the beginning of the 1ST month, she is losing at a rate of -2400 per month, but at the end of the month, she is losing at a rate of 2000 per month. this is not a constant rate. so if we average it, she is losing -2200 over the whole month

Comment: since she is losing 2200 in the first month, that 2200 has to be p(0.5)

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit further. i am having trouble how you get the value -2400. it would be appreaciated if you could show the working

Comment: okay so let's say i make $\$1$ the first hour, $\$3$ the second hour, $\$5$ the third hour, etc. the expression will *not* actually be $1+2x$. Why? Because I need to make an average of $\$1$/hour during the first hour. If we use the expression $0+2x$, i'll be making $\$0$/hour at first, then $\$2$/hour at the end of the first hour, which means for the WHOLE hour, i'll make $\$1$/hour on average